# Parse nested payload in custom dimensions Log Analytics, Kusto Query

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics

I have some nested payload as a part of custom dimensions and I would like to filter by some parameter of that payload. For example, the payload is:

```
{\"Number\":\"\",\"Number\":\"123\",\"A\":false,\"B\":true,\"C\":true,\"D\":1661507873379}
```

I need to have property A be as a separate column and to see its value.
for example:

So it would be easier for me to filter devices with that particular value of that parameter

For now, I tried to use:

```
traces 
| where tostring(customDimensions['SN']) == '123'
| where message contains "A"
| extend pay = customDimensions["Payload"]
| extend pay2 = parse_json(pay)
| extend pay3 = parse_json(tostring(parse_json(pay2))).A
```

But I am getting an empty pay3 column.

I was trying to use recommended solution for here
[Problem with Kusto Query with nested JSON parameters Sentinel Log Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71428497/problem-with-kusto-query-with-nested-json-parameters-sentinel-log-analytics)

but it doesn’t work(

Comment: Please share the entire `customDimensions` (no need for the siblings of `Payload`, I just want to see how everything is constructed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you understand the way these logs were written is terribly wrong :-)

```
// Data sample generation. Not part of the solution.
let traces = datatable (customDimensions:dynamic)
[
dynamic({"MessageTemplate":"Event {EventType} received from {Empty}. Offset: {Offset}. Payload: {Payload}. Partition: {Partition}","SourceContext":"None","Name":"Service","Abc":"B5PJ","Partition":"1","UtcTimestamp":"2022-08-23T07:12:51.63457133Z","Field":"TT","Type":"BB","Payload":"{\\\"F\\\":\\\"3\\\",\\\"D\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"B\\\":true,\\\"A\\\":true,\\\"C\\\":true,\\\"E\\\":2}","Offset":"145645646453"})
];
// Solution starts here
traces
| project Payload = todynamic(tostring(todynamic(strcat('"', customDimensions.Payload, '"'))))
| evaluate bag_unpack(Payload)
```

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| true | true | true | 1 | 2 | 3 |